# No puedo visualizar lo programado JAVA en Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans-8.2

Hice el programa para visualizar cubo 3D

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package cube3d;

/**
 *
 */
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.Transform3D;
import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;



public class Cube3D {


        public Cube3D() {
        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
        BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
        ColorCube cube = new ColorCube(0.1);
        TransformGroup GT = new TransformGroup();
        Transform3D transform = new Transform3D();

        GT.setTransform(transform);
        GT.addChild(cube);
        group.addChild(GT);
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(group);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

La salida muestra

run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Pero no veo la figura. Qué puedo hacer. Ayuda

Comment: Quizas programar el main para ello ....

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que indicar qué ejecutar en el main. Fíjate que viene escrito dentro del método. Ahora mismo sólo te está compilando.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

Para ejecutar la clase Cube3D te bastaría hacer esto

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cube3D cubo3D = new Cube3D();
}
```